# Reactjs and data on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, reactjs, frameworks

I'm new to Javascript frameworks and looking for framework for my new projects. Until now i created simple apps using MVC framework Django with Bootstrap frontend. Thanks framework i got everything in one package with best-practice well know. For Javascript i used some jQuery libraries without understanding, just configured with doc help.

When i tried to write some Javascript on my own and found there are big changes in JS world (like ES6, TypeScript) i found it very usefull. When i found JS frameworks, i felt in love.

I have read about frameworks, watched some tutorials. As many other, i found React nice. But what i'm completely missing, is the server part. Especially React tutorials creates components or functions, nice UI, but don't cover what happens with data next. I know that React is ment as "V" in MVC. But what is the best-practice or wide-used extension for server part? Are there tutorials or book to take me further than just creating actions and UI?

Thanks for any links, i just need to point best direction. Or is React ment for just specific project parts and better to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, yes there are quite a number of tutorials and most of them don't cover how do you deploy node apps on the servers. I'll assume you have some server admin knowledge so I'll skip straight to the meat of the setup.

## The Server Setup

Regardless of it being a simple static page, a single page API or a react app, you will need to have Node.js installed on any server you will want it to run. Second you will need a production process manager for Node.js. My personal favourite is [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). The process manages makes sure your app is always on and restarts it if it goes down for whatever reason. You will also need a reverse proxy server (you need this for security and SEO purposes). Again, a go-to for it is Nginx (it's a competitor of Apache)

Two very good tutorials for setting up your server are
[Tut #1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)
[Tut #2](http://blog.danyll.com/setting-up-express-with-nginx-and-pm2/)

## The App Setup

Apart from all the server setup you need to handle routing for your app (what happens when you to go to /blog or /login). A stable standard right now is [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/). You can do without but then you will need to write a lot of the manual routing by hand in Node.js You will set up Express to server back your Index file and any others you may need.

A good tutorial for configuring your Express for a React app is [Video Tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoJuOs-niIc).
He does show a bit more but that is on later videos. You can stop once you get the gist of it.

*Advanced Stuff*

There's also the matter if you want the JavaScript to be rendered on the server or on the client side. For that you will need to make some more configuration for you app. The video tutorial I linked above should show you how to set that up as well if you are interested.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I hoped there will be much easier way, but i will investigate to read all links. I'm used to server side programming and it's, in my eyes, very simple get it working.